# How do I find the fully qualified name of an assembly?

Tags: c#, deployment, assemblies, strongname

How do I find out the fully qualified name of my assembly such as:

```
MyNamespace.MyAssembly, version=1.0.3300.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
```

I've managed to get my PublicKeyToken using the `sn.exe` in the SDK, but I'ld like to easily get the full qualified name.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you can load the assembly into a .NET application, you can do:

```
typeof(SomeTypeInTheAssembly).Assembly.FullName
```

If you cannot then you can use ildasm.exe and it will be in there somewhere:

```
ildasm.exe MyAssembly.dll /text
```

Comment: Actually, that gives you the assembly in which SomeTypeInTheAssembly resides, which you may not have at compile time.

Comment: And I'm not sure "in there somewhere" qualifies as an answer. That ildasm command results in a wall of text, not well formatted. Several of the suggestions below are more complete.

Comment: You can search the output for "MyAssembly, Version=" to find it. If you have grep installed:

ildasm.exe MyAssembly.dll /text | grep -A 1 "MyAssembly, Version="

Comment: Unfortunately when the Assembly is obfuscated then the solution with ildasm.exe will not work.

Comment: ```ildasm.exe MyAssembly.dll /text``` does NOT contain full assembly name anywhere in the text. This method is misleading and inaccurate.

Answer (score 153):

This is a shameless copy-paste from [I Note It Down](http://inoteitdown.blogspot.co.nz/2011/07/get-assembly-fully-qualified-name.html) and is a simple way to get the FQN for the project output:

```
Open Visual Studio
Go to Tools –> External Tools –> Add
    Title: Get Qualified Assembly Name
    Command: Powershell.exe
    Arguments: -command "[System.Reflection.AssemblyName]::GetAssemblyName(\"$(TargetPath)\").FullName"
    Check "Use Output Window".
```

The new tool appears under `Tools –> Get Qualified Assembly Name`. When the menu item is selected, the assembly name is given in the output window.

Comment: Microsoft, The year is 2015. Please provide us with a better alternative to get the fully qualified assembly name.

Comment: This should be the selected answer

Comment: Seconding @M3579's comment, have some bounty.

Comment: This is the most convenient way of checking this ever!

Comment: The question did not specify "for the current project."  I suspect the author wants this for any assembly, including dependencies.

Answer (score 26):

Late to the party, but googled some more about this issue and found this page:

- http://www.pvle.be/2010/04/getting-an-assemblys-strong-name-with-powershell/

He describes a powershell function that can do this. So. I've never ever used powershell before, but I thought I'd give it a try:

```
C:\> cd PATH_TO_ASSEMBLY   
C:\PATH_TO_ASSEMBLY>powershell
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\PATH_TO_ASSEMBLY> [System.Reflection.AssemblyName]::GetAssemblyName('System.Data.SQLite.dll').FullName
System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.66.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139
PS C:\PATH_TO_ASSEMBLY>
```

This does the trick mentioned in other answers by using code, except you don't have to create a project to do this - just type away at the prompt ;)

Comment: Thanks! Ended using the C# version of this `AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(assemblyPath).FullName`

Comment: And a suggestion is to use the full path to the assembly name and not just the assembly name. FWIW, it doesn't work if you give that way and even if you are in the same directory as the assembly.

Comment: This seems to try to load the file from my home directory rather than the current directory. `PS C:\projects\sphw\bin\Debug> [System.Reflection.AssemblyName]::GetAssemblyName('sphw.dll').FullName` gives the error `MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "GetAssemblyName" with "1" argument(s): "Could not find file 'C:\Users\mikeblas\sphw.dll'."`  Why is that?

Comment: @MikeB I'm just guessing here, but maybe you need to load the assembly first. I'm guessing `System.Data.SQLite` just happened to either already be loaded or was within the "searchpath" for assemblies.

Answer (score 9):

Use [Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly.aspx) to get the current assembly, use [Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getentryassembly.aspx) to get the assembly that started it all, or use [Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getcallingassembly.aspx) to get the assembly of the code that called your function (one up in the stack).

Once you have the right assembly, use the FullName property, as indicated in other answers.

Answer (score 6):

Also if you're looking for the Fully Qualified Name for an assembly already in the GAC you can launch a Visual Studio Command Prompt (easiest way to set the correct paths) and use `gacutil /l` to list all assemblies with their respective FQNs. Use `gacutil /l <yourassemblyname>` to filter the list to more easily find what you're looking for.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use open source ILSpy, after you load your assembly it's full name will be 
diplayed in comments at the top of code window

Answer (score 5):

If you load the assembly (DLL, EXE, etc.) in [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) it will tell you the full strong name at the bottom.

Comment: This answer is out of line, he was not asking for a $118 plug-in to find this out.

Comment: At the time this was posted Reflector was free.

Comment: ILSpy is a free alternative for Reflector which can be used to find the fully qualified name of an assembly.

Comment: Old .Net Reflector 6.8.2.5 is free and it is working.

Comment: Nowadays [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) (by JetBrains) is the best free alternative for this purpose.

Comment: dotPeek does NOT display the full name, or even the public key.

Answer (score 4):

JetBrains [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) or Telerik [JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) are quite good. Just open the DLL and you have the name right away.

Answer (score 1):

Couple ways.

In code:

[Assembly.FullName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.fullname.aspx)
 e.g.

```
typeof(Thingy).Assembly.FullName
```

or, if its an installed assembly, from the GAC using the steps [in this post on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2exyydhb.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Being old-school and liking cmd better than powershell, I wrote myself this batch script to do it:

```
@REM fqn.bat <dll_path>
powershell -command "([system.reflection.assembly]::loadfile('%~f1')).FullName"
```

The `%~f1` expands the first parameter to be an absolute path, so running:

```
fqn mydll.dll
```

Will print the fully-qualified name you want.