# How to debug this WCF error?

Tags: .net, wcf, .net-3.5

When trying to run or reference the service project I get this error:

`The type 'MyCompany.MyNameSpace.MyType', provided as  the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive could not be found.`

Where to look to fix this?

**Edit:**
This is while running under the buit in vs 2008 cassini.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WCF, Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive could not be found. ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/720807/wcf-service-attribute-value-in-the-servicehost-directive-could-not-be-found)

Comment: dont delete - I am not using IIS at this point in any sort or manner...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message means that the type specified as the Service type couldn't be loaded. Type loading problems can be debugged using the Fusion loader log. [See here for a good explanation](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

[WCF, Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720807/wcf-service-attribute-value-in-the-servicehost-directive-could-not-be-found)

Comment: would gladly accept but I am not using IIS, all I am trying is to reference the service from another proj in the solution or run it in cassini.

Answer (score 0):

- Check your svc html file for the tag: <%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="Service" CodeBehind="~/App_Code/Service.cs" %>
- If explicitly setup in IIS make sure the virtual folder is a web application
- You can enable WCF tracing by allowing me to link you to my blog post because I am evil and want to generate more traffic to my website to be all important :) 
  http://jtstroup.net/post/Wcf-Tracing.aspx