# WCF Web Service error: The type 'ExampleTeste45.Web.Service.SilverlightWCF', provided as

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, silverlight

In a Silverlight project when publish and try accessing a service http://griduni.uninova.pt/sidac/Service/SilverlightWCF.svc get the error message that apears.

[image]

my Web.config

```
    <configuration>
        <system.web>
          <customErrors mode="Off"/>
          <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
          </compilation>
          <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />

        </system.web>


        <system.serviceModel>

          <!--<serviceHostingEnvironment>
            <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
              <add prefix="http://griduni.uninova.pt"/>
            </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
          </serviceHostingEnvironment>-->

            <!--<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
                multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />-->

            <bindings>
                <customBinding>
                    <binding name="ExampleTeste45.Web.Service.SilverlightWCF.customBinding0">
                        <binaryMessageEncoding />
                        <httpTransport />
                    </binding>
                </customBinding>
            </bindings>
            <!--<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
                multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />-->
            <services>
                <service name="ExampleTeste45.Web.Service.SilverlightWCF"
                    behaviorConfiguration="SimpleServiceBehavior">
                    <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding"
                    bindingConfiguration="ExampleTeste45.Web.Service.SilverlightWCF.customBinding0"
                    contract="ExampleTeste45.Web.Service.SilverlightWCF" />

                    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
                </service>
            </services>
            <behaviors>
                <serviceBehaviors>
                    <behavior name="SimpleServiceBehavior">
                        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                    </behavior>
                </serviceBehaviors>
            </behaviors>
            <!--<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
                multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />-->
        </system.serviceModel>
    </configuration>
```

my Service Markup:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="ExampleTeste45.Web.Service.SilverlightWCF" CodeBehind="SilverlightWCF.svc.cs" %>
```

[image]

the solutions that i saw by google didn't work , the Service="ExampleTeste45.Web.Service.SilverlightWCF" in Markup is correct the endpoint addres is blank by definition and I saw that its getting the right addres, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Also I wanted to know why you have commented<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"                 multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" Node

Comment: it was giving another error so commented to see if solve the problem and since disapered the error that was showing and building the solution gave no error i let it stay commented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<host>
<baseAddresses>
<add baseaddress="http://YourSiteNameORyourhostingmachineName/" /> </baseAddresses>
</host>
```

In the end before closing `</service>` node

Comment: Please check the following links .. and please let me know the option that worked for you.. 1. http://forums.asp.net/t/1764739.aspx?The+type+Service+provided+as+the+Service+attribute+value+in+the+ServiceHost+directive+or+provided+in+the+configuration+element+system+serviceModel+serviceHostingEnvironment+serviceActivations+could+not+be+found+

Comment: 2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/720807/wcf-service-attribute-value-in-the-servicehost-directive-could-not-be-found

Comment: had allready seen those two links ,but for the correte answer in the seconde link didn't get what he was refering to the virtual directory if it the folder named Service that i have but tryed Convert to Web Application but the same error still shows the rest answers didn't work because most were missing some dll or part of code that wasn't in my case (dll: EntityFramework.dll, ExampleTeste45.Web.dll, ExampleTeste45.Web.pdb and some others dlls)

Comment: the first link my bin is inside another folder in host /SIDAC/bin but supposedly /SIDAC is my root folder..

Comment: afther all the solution is the one given in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/720807/wcf-service-attribute-value-in-the-servicehost-directive-could-not-be-found but the folder he was refering is the folder in the server and I hand't get that so afther done it started to work.

Answer (score 0):

In your service element you may need to add your interface to the contract attribute - contract="ISilverlightWCF"

```
<service name="ExampleTeste45.Web.Service.SilverlightWCF"
                behaviorConfiguration="SimpleServiceBehavior">
                <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="ExampleTeste45.Web.Service.SilverlightWCF.customBinding0"
                contract="ISilverlightWCF" />
```

Comment: gives this warning : Warning 1 The 'contract' attribute is invalid - The value 'ISilverlightWCF' is invalid according to its datatype 'serviceContractType' - The Enumeration constraint failed. And the error still appears no luck =(