# The type 'AjaxControlToolkit.Sanitizer.HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider' is ambiguous

Tags: vb.net, web-config, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a problem in my web.config file. I have added html editor in my website, and configured the web.config file as per instruction but I am getting this error:

```
**Parser Error Message:** The type 'AjaxControlToolkit.Sanitizer.HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider' is ambiguous: it could come from assembly 'C:\Users\358676\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\WebSites\TheHubPortal\bin\AjaxControlToolkit.DLL' or from assembly 'C:\Users\358676\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\WebSites\TheHubPortal\bin\SanitizerProviders.DLL'. Please specify the assembly explicitly in the type name.

    Source Error: 



Line 15:     <sanitizer defaultProvider="HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider">
Line 16:       <providers>
**Line 17:         <add name="HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider" type="AjaxControlToolkit.Sanitizer.HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider"></add>**
Line 18:       </providers>
Line 19:     </sanitizer>
```

This is my Code:

```
    <%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Admin.aspx.vb" Inherits="AdminPages_Admin" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor" TagPrefix="asp" %>


<asp:HtmlEditorExtender ID="HtmlEditorExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="NewsBodyTextBox" DisplaySourceTab="true">
                                                            <Toolbar>
                                                                <asp:Undo />
                                                                <asp:Redo />
                                                                <asp:Bold />
                                                                <asp:Italic />
                                                                <asp:Underline />
                                                                <asp:StrikeThrough />
                                                                <asp:Subscript />
                                                                <asp:Superscript />
                                                                <asp:JustifyLeft />
                                                                <asp:JustifyCenter />
                                                                <asp:JustifyRight />
                                                                <asp:JustifyFull />
                                                                <asp:InsertOrderedList />
                                                                <asp:InsertUnorderedList />
                                                                <asp:CreateLink />
                                                                <asp:UnLink />
                                                                <asp:RemoveFormat />
                                                                <asp:SelectAll />
                                                                <asp:UnSelect />
                                                                <asp:Delete />
                                                                <asp:Cut />
                                                                <asp:Copy />
                                                                <asp:Paste />
                                                                <asp:BackgroundColorSelector />
                                                                <asp:ForeColorSelector />
                                                                <asp:FontNameSelector />
                                                                <asp:FontSizeSelector />
                                                                <asp:Indent />
                                                                <asp:Outdent />
                                                                <asp:InsertHorizontalRule />
                                                                <asp:HorizontalSeparator />
                                                                <asp:InsertImage />
                                                            </Toolbar>
                                                        </asp:HtmlEditorExtender>
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Did you read the entire error message? "... *it could come from assembly 'C:\Users\358676\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\WebSites\TheHubPortal\bin\AjaxControlToolkit.DLL' or from assembly 'C:\Users\358676\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\WebSites\TheHubPortal\bin\SanitizerProviders.DLL'. **Please specify the assembly explicitly in the type name.***"

Comment: Yeah I know, I read the whole error message. I've tried to delete those dll files and add it again, then rebuild the website but I am still getting that error. I don't know the work around in this type of error that's why I am asking if you guys have any idea or links to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Windows Powershell to get the fully qualified name of your assembly.  Source from [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658446/how-do-i-find-the-fully-qualified-name-of-an-assembly):

```
C:\> cd PATH_TO_ASSEMBLY   
C:\PATH_TO_ASSEMBLY>powershell
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\PATH_TO_ASSEMBLY> [System.Reflection.AssemblyName]::GetAssemblyName('System.Data.SQLite.dll').FullName
**System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.66.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139**
PS C:\PATH_TO_ASSEMBLY>
```

From that you need to replace the 'System.Data.SQLite.dll' with the filename of the assembly you actually want to use.  Take the fully qualified name (highlighted with **) and change your line to look like this:

```
<add name="HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider" type="AjaxControlToolkit.Sanitizer.HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider, Version=X.X.X.X, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3d5c5b1a7743"></add>
```

Make that match your fully qualified name, of course.  After that your ambiguity problem should go away.