# System.IO.FileLoadException occurred in unknown module in MFC project using a WPF user control

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-c++, mfc, interop

I have a project in MFC that uses a WPF user control targeting .NET 4.0. When I run the program I get the following exception

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred
>   in Unknown Module.
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'MyProject'
>   , Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of
>   its dependencies. Could not find or load a type. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80131522)

When I break the execution, It shows following module information

```
Version: 6.3.9600.16384 (winblue_rtm.130821-1623)
Original Location: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
```

I tried single stepping from the begining, but the first time I hit F10 I get this exception. Can anyone please explain to me this exception/issue?

Comment: FileMon usually helps me in these situations, not sure if you tried that yet.

Comment: @EkoostikMartin FileMon now part of the process monitor in system internal kit.

Comment: There is not enough information here to say what is wrong, but my guess is that "MyProject" is your .Net control and for some reason it is not being found.  Show your hosting code (C++), the results of fusion logging (http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx), and the full assembly name (via `ildasm` or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/658446/how-do-i-find-the-fully-qualified-name-of-an-assembly)

Comment: @Matt - I know, I still call it FileMon though!

Comment: Have you seen error massage in  Event viewer.

Comment: Try:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26650375/is-there-any-class-count-limit-in-mfc-project-compiled-with-clr