# How to get .RDLC files from dll and put them to reportviewer control?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, reflection, reporting-services, reportviewer

I have 2 projects as follow:

First: All reports(rdlc files) are here.

[image: Class Library]

Second: **SharePoint 2010** solution that shows my reports.

[image: SharePoint 2010 Project]

I use following code to access **RDLC** file in dll and put it in `reportviewer` control in **SharePoint Application Page** in second project:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("ReportsLib.dll");
Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("ReportsLib.MyReport.rdlc");
reportViewer.LocalReport.LoadReportDefinition(stream);
```

When i want to get **rdlc** file from `ReportsLib` (for example: MyReport.rdlc) and put it in reportviewer control in SharePoint Application Pages, following error occurred:

```
[FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\ReportsLib.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
   System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection) +0
   System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +416
   System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(String assemblyFile) +52
   HRS.ReportsViewer.Layouts.ShowReport.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +77
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +25
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +42
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +132
   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +101
   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.LayoutsPageBase.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +49
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +66
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2428
```

What do i do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The assembly name appears to be `ReportsLib`, and assuming that you've used the default namespaces, you'll need to adjust like so:

```
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("ReportsLib.dll");
var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("ReportsLib.MyReport.rdlc");
reportViewer.LocalReport.LoadReportDefinition(stream);
```

Also, if you move `MyReport.rdlc` into a folder, then you'll need to add a dotted folder path as well, i.e.

```
GetManifestResourceStream("ReportsLib.SomeFolder.MyReport.rdlc");
```

**Edit** If the assembly has been GAC'ed, try providing the fully qualified assembly name e.g.

```
 var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("ReportsLib.dll, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
```

You can obtain the FQN using one of the methods here:
[How do I find the fully qualified name of an assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658446/how-do-i-find-the-fully-qualified-name-of-an-assembly)

Comment: thnx, please checked my edited question. it was my mistake but in code i use `ReportsLib`.

Comment: `ReportsLib.dll` has deployed in shrepoint bin folder and GAC.

Comment: Another error raised:`Could not load file or assembly 'file:///c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\ReportsLib.dll, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified`

Comment: You did replace `xxx` and version with the actual attributes from the FQN of your assembly, right?

Comment: I replaced real `PublicKeyToken` and `Version` with `xxx`, I get them from `C:\Windows\assembly` (GAC) folder.

Comment: One last thing I can think of is to now right click on the `ReportsLib` assembly reference and copy local=false, global=true because it is now in the GAC. In fact, because it is in the GAC AND you load it dynamically, you probably don't need to reference it from the Sharepoint project at all.