# AppDomain.Load() throws System.IO.FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, .net

I try to create new application domain and load new assembly:

```
AppDomain newDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("SecondaryDomain");

newDomain.AssemblyLoad += (sender, eventArgs) => Console.WriteLine("Assembly loaded");
newDomain.DomainUnload += (sender, EventArgs) => Console.WriteLine("Domain unloaded");

Console.WriteLine($"New domain name: {newDomain.FriendlyName}");
newDomain.Load(new AssemblyName("System.Dynamic"));

foreach (Assembly assembly in newDomain.GetAssemblies())
    Console.WriteLine($"Assembly in secondary domain: {assembly.GetName().Name}");

AppDomain.Unload(newDomain);
```

It throws `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` even if reference to `System.Dynamic` is added. How to solve it?

Comment: System.Dynamic is a namespace name, not an assembly name.  Classes in that namespace live inside System.Core.dll.  If you do this in a .NETCore etc project then you ought to mention that.

Comment: Yes, You're right, however, it seems that fully qualified name of the assembly has also to be used for the `AssemblyName` instance to be constructed properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating `AssemblyName` instance with a string parameter, You should use the assembly **fully qualified name**, as mentioned [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6ccxba0(v=vs.110).aspx). So, instead writing only the assembly name, You should also specify its version, culture and public key token.

When using the assembly fully qualified name, the line that loads the assembly may look similar to this one:

```
newDomain.Load(new AssemblyName("System.Dynamic, Version=<version>, Culture=<culture>, PublicKeyToken=<public key token>"));
```

but **placeholders marked with `<` and `>` should be replaced with proper values**.

For more information about assembly fully qualified names, You can take a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyname.fullname(v=vs.110).aspx).

There are several ways to get fully qualified name of an assembly.
If You have any problems obtaining this full name of the assembly You want to load, You can take a look at these links:

- [How to: Determine an Assembly's Fully Qualified Name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/how-to-determine-assembly-fully-qualified-name)
- [How do I find the fully qualified name of an assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658446/how-do-i-find-the-fully-qualified-name-of-an-assembly)

**UPDATE**

As *Hans Passant* mentioned in his comment, `System.Dynamic` namespace seems to be located inside `System.Core` assembly, so make sure which assembly You really want to load.